# Simple first-child not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I thought I understood this, but apparently not.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/w6nMe/2/

```
$('p:first-child').css({color:'red'});
```

Is not changing the colour of **any** text.

```
<div class="post text"> <a href="#">this is a url</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex optio velit culpa nisi nemo ab voluptatem vitae voluptate molestiae recusandae? Ipsa dolorum ut dignissimos ipsam doloribus itaque reprehenderit nostrum a.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex optio velit culpa nisi nemo ab voluptatem vitae voluptate molestiae recusandae? Ipsa dolorum ut dignissimos ipsam doloribus itaque reprehenderit nostrum a.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex optio velit culpa nisi nemo ab voluptatem vitae voluptate molestiae recusandae? Ipsa dolorum ut dignissimos ipsam doloribus itaque reprehenderit nostrum a.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex optio velit culpa nisi nemo ab voluptatem vitae voluptate molestiae recusandae? Ipsa dolorum ut dignissimos ipsam doloribus itaque reprehenderit nostrum a.</p>
</div>
<div class="post text"> <a href="#">this is a url</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex optio velit culpa nisi nemo ab voluptatem vitae voluptate molestiae recusandae? Ipsa dolorum ut dignissimos ipsam doloribus itaque reprehenderit nostrum a.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex optio velit culpa nisi nemo ab voluptatem vitae voluptate molestiae recusandae? Ipsa dolorum ut dignissimos ipsam doloribus itaque reprehenderit nostrum a.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex optio velit culpa nisi nemo ab voluptatem vitae voluptate molestiae recusandae? Ipsa dolorum ut dignissimos ipsam doloribus itaque reprehenderit nostrum a.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like i need to read again DOC on first-child ;) In fact, none of your P tags are first-child

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for:

```
$('p:first').css({color:'red'});
```

UPDATE:

selecting first `<p>` on any `<div>`

```
$('div p:first-of-type').css({color:'red'});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aYZKP/2/)

Comment: That only going to target the first p tag that find in the dom tree, is no going to select the first-child p tag for every parent .post.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$('p:first').css({color:'red'});
```

Change

```
p:first-child {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

to

```
p:first-of-type {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/w6nMe/9/)

Comment: `:first-of-type` looks like what OP wants +1

Answer (score 0):

Try **[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** or **[:eq(0)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** like,

```
$('p:first').css({color:'red'});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w6nMe/4/) and [Eq demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w6nMe/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to select the first p tag child of every parent post, here is my solution:

`$('div.post p:first-child').css({color:'red'})`

Answer (score 0):

try This Code:

```
$(function() {
  $("p:first").addClass("first");
});
```

css :`p.first { color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

In css `:first-child` selector is used to select the specified selector, only if it is the first child of its parent.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/X48uh/1/)**:

**CSS**:

```
p:first-child {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of hack. you may include the following in your jquery.

```
$('p:nth-child(2)').css({color:'red'});
```